# What is the next number? 24,54,90,120,168,210,240,288,360,440

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

> Question : What is the next number in the following sequence? (not finite)
>
> $$\large24,54,90,120,168,210,240,288,360,440,\dots$$

***My Solution***

- I'm trying a closed form solution
- I tried computing the differences- they don't converge
- Tried finding the relationship between their binary equivalents
- A trivial observation : all numbers are divisible by $6$ except $440$

**Edit-1**: Seeing the downvotes, I want to clarify something: All I'm trying to do is to find a solution (an expresssion) that represents the sequence

**Edit-2** : This question was given by my Math Teacher as a fun exercise in puzzle solving . It is not for a graded homework

Comment: I just changed the title so that it describes the question in a way distinguishable from other questions. Hope you don't mind. PS: welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Where did you get this sequence from? Are you certain it's correct (see the last para of my answer)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This question was given to us by our math teacher. (according to him:it is a "just for fun" question)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better suited to Math.SE.

Comment: @AE can we vote to migrate?

Comment: @ForIInRange, I think it's something we need a mod to do. I've flagged it.

Comment: Doing a quick search on Math.SE, it looks like "find the next term in this sequence" questions aren't too well received there

Comment: If it was copied by a teacher on the blackboard and then copied down by you, there is a potential for errors.  Could it be https://oeis.org/A090821 (as suggested by GOTO0)?  There would be a 48 missing after 24 and a 420 instead of 440.

Comment: If you are looking for any solution that fits, a simple overfitted polynomial will give you your answer.

Comment: So this is now closed. & I copied this on Excel and the answer is 442, LOL :D
Since there is no right answer I found below; could you pls let us know the right one?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is

> 4x6, 6x9, 9x10, 10x12, 12x14, 14x15, 15x16, 16x18, 18x20, 20x22, ...

So we have a sequence 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, ... such that

> the products of adjacent pairs of terms in *this* sequence gives the OP's original sequence.

I'd guess the next term in *this* sequence is 24, so that the answer to the OP's question is

> 22x24 = **528**,

but I'm not certain how to back this up!

One possibility is that there's a mistake in the question and our new sequence should in fact be 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, ..., the sequence of composite numbers, as @GOTO0 suggested. Otherwise, I need to give it more thought.

Comment: I was tempted to think of the product of successive composite numbers, but where are 8 and 21?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How did you guess 24?

Comment: @Reptilian Most of the gaps between successive terms in the new sequence seem to be 2. But only most, so I'm not certain of 24.

Comment: @randal'thor 24 makes sense in this sequence: (2 multiples of 2) (next highest multiple of 3) (3 multiples of 2) (next highest multiple of 3) (4 multiples of 2) (next highest multiple of 3). Of course, it could only be odd multiples of 3, in which case the next multiplier would be 27.

Comment: @Roger That really doesn't sound like a neat mathematical rule, as we would expect from this kind of question

Comment: It's probably the natural number sequence without primes. 24 would be the next, because 23 is prime.

Answer (score 3):

*Unless this is the intended answer, in which case it's a bad question anyway, this answer serves to show how broad the question is.*

We can always extend a sequence by taking the difference of subsequent elements, which yields a sequence with one fewer number. Once we get a list where all numbers are the same (which will eventually happen if we "bottom out" to get 1 element, but may happen sooner), we can start extending that bottom-most list and propagate the answer up to the top.

```
24, 54, 90, 120, 168, 210, 240, 288, 360, 440
30, 36, 30, 48, 42, 30, 48, 72, 80
6, -6, 18, -6, -12, 18, 24, 8
-12, 24, -24, -6, 30, 6, -16
36, -48, 18, 36, -24, -22
-84, 66, 18, -60, 2
150, -48, -78, 62
-198, -30, 140
168, 170
2
```

In this case we go all the way down and get to the value 2. The next element in such a list is the sum of all the rightmost numbers:

> 2 + 170 + 140 + 62 + 2 - 22 - 16 + 8 + 80 + 440 = **866**

This yields a **polynomial fit** to your problem which is guaranteed to always produce integers (and, after a while, to always produce distinct increasing integers).

Comment: Sorry warspy, but that's obviously wrong!

Comment: It's a valid answer and can correctly continue the sequence for infinity. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: I meant it's obviously not the intended answer (but I didn't DV!) It shows that the question is bad; sequence questions generally are. Someone should add a comment to [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/what-is-the-next-number-in-this-sequence) saying so. (I would have, but h34 is an old enemy of mine IRL, so...)

Comment: @warspyking while the method of determining a sequence rule based on the differences between terms is usually valid, it does not apply to this case. The final tier of differences that you reached was $-60$, but then you assumed that this was the very final tier possible. In order to be sure that a tier is the final tier of differences, there must be a tier size of larger than $1$. Hope this answered your question!

Comment: I wouldn't say *all* continue the sequence puzzles are bad. Just *most* of them. I think this answer is funny.

Comment: @Lopsy No new ideas went into this answer: just differencing until you've got only one term left. The same thing could be done to *any* sequence to get the next term. OK, the question is probably bad, but this answer is *really* bad.

Comment: @rand The point of this answer is to show how broad the question is.

Comment: @rand I'm also not gonna get rep lost, it's CW!

Comment: @warspyking - Wittgenstein said the next term in any sequence could be anything you like. I've never considered that to be a very helpful observation. Is that the point you're making? I don't think this question is very interesting, but while you say you're seeking to demonstrate that it's "broad", you don't succeed, if by "broad" you mean that several reasonable answers are possible and one doesn't stand out as more reasonable than the others. Having read the above, I think that must be what you do mean.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: According to [Sequence solver](http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/hn/sequence/), this is correct.