# Find the next number in the sequence below?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Find the next number in the sequence below:

> 298 209 129 58 ?

Source: [Briddles.com](http://www.briddles.com/2013/04/find-next-number-in-sequence.html?source=stack&external=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next number is

> -4

because

> the successive differences form an arithmetic progression:
>
>  `A:   298    209    129     58    -4`
>  `B:       89     80     71     62`
>  `C:           9      9      9`

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but isn't this basically the same as fitting a second degree polynomial to three of the data points, noticing that the there's exactly *one* additional data point supporting the parabola hypothesis, and then extrapolating from there.

Comment: @Bass Kinda, yes, but I think in this case it's justified. The fact that the double-differences are the same indicates that I'm not just [randomly fitting a polynomial to the data](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6493/5373). (I also checked some other places where this puzzle is found online, and they all seem to have the same solution.)

Comment: Isn't it the defining characteristic of a second degree polynomial that the second differences are constant and non-zero?

Comment: @Bass No ... those two 9's in the 2nd row didn't have to be equal to each other; indeed, it says something significant about the sequence that they aren't.

Comment: The significant thing it says is that the fourth data point fits the very same second degree polynomial that was defined by the first three data points. I don't think there's any fundamental difference between fitting a polynomial of the lowest possible order and taking successive differences until all the values are identical.

Comment: @Bass _shrug_ It looks like I won't convince you, but the OP accepted this answer and it seems to be generally accepted on the internet as the solution to this sequence puzzle. Maybe that means it's an uninteresting puzzle, but can you find any more convincing answer?

Comment: @Bass: [Indeed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+298+209+129+58), $R^2$ is $1$ with $(9 x^2)/2 - (205 x)/2 + 396 $

Comment: I'm not sure I need convincing; I agree that in this case, the polynomial fit by [method of differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine#Method_of_differences) did find a parabola that fits all four points. My complaint is just that for any three points, such a parabola exists, so just one more data point is somewhat of a meager sample size. But I guess that's a universal problem when continuing such short sequences.

Comment: "The fact that the double-differences are the same indicates that I'm not just randomly fitting a polynomial to the data." But *all* polynomial fits will give you nth order differences that are the same! When you do a polynomial fit (with evenly spaced inputs), you're essentially taking successive differences until you find a row that's all the same, then continuing that row. That's why Bass is complaining. (It's a correct solution according to the poser, but that doesn't make it any more fitting.)

Comment: Hmm, this all sounds like a ripe source for a puzzle. A bit math heavy, of course, but polynomial fitting by using only addition and subtraction sounds puzzlingly enough, and the method isn't in the curriculum anymore these days, so it should be interesting too. I'll try to make it a good one, and post it later today. Anyone reading this comment is kindly requested to not answer that question, because spoilerous. :-)

Comment: Turned out very maths-y, but [here it is](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60747/36023) anyway.

Comment: @Deusovi "*until you find a row that's all the same*" - yes, and how fitting the solution is depends on how long that row is. If you had a row of 10 which were all the same, that'd be pretty strong proof that it's the right solution. If it was only a row of 1, then there'd be no real evidence for the solution at all. A row of 2 is somewhere in between - not so compelling as a much longer row, but still evidence towards a successive-differences solution. In the absence of any *better* solution ...

Answer (score 7):

The next number in this sequence is:

> $-4$

Because:

> $$298 - 90 + 1 = 209$$$$209 - 80 + 0 = 128$$$$129 - 70 + (- 1) = 58$$ Notice a pattern? The recurrence relation is as follows: $$S_n=S_{n-1}-90+10n-(n-1)=S_{n-1}-89+9n$$ with $S_0=289$. Simply using this relation for the next term, $58-89+9\cdot 3=\boxed{-4}$.